# Windows 7 VM using VMware Video Drivers

Tags: windows-7, display

When I remote desktop into a Windows 7 VM, it says the display adapters being used are VMWare SVGA 3d. Is there any way to use the system's native drivers (particularly with OpenGL support)?

Comment: What makes you think that isn't the native driver?  I'm assuming it's a VMware VM, based on the fact that that driver is installed at all - which would make that the proper native driver.  What product is it virtualized under?  You'd need a desktop VMware product (Workstation, Fusion), not a server product (ESX[i]), to get OpenGL support.

Comment: I guess I just saw VMWare and assumed it was something going on with the RDP. I'll check with our sysadmin.

Comment: Is this remote PC a virtual machine? Sounds like it.

Comment: It is, correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is a virtual machine, you don't need to check with your admin: You can't use the native graphics card, as VMWare doesn't allow any access to it. VM's are not meant for good graphics performance.

Comment: Vmware VMs aren't meant for good graphic performance, true.  But HyperVMs can leverage native graphics cards using the RemoteFX feature, which reputedly gives outstanding graphics performance to VMs.

Comment: [VMware supports hardware accelerated graphics](http://www.vmware.com/support/ws55/doc/ws_vidsound_d3d_enabling_host.html) as do several other VM solutions.